# Aluminium front and carbon rear wheel on hardtail?

Tags: wheels, dynamo

I recently got a used hardtail MTB. (Specialized Epic Elite)

It's got Roval SL Control 29 - which is pricey. The front has 24 spokes and back has 28 spokes.

Now I want to install a dynamo on it and found out there are not many dynamos for 24 spoke wheels.

And I'm not sure If it's a good idea to use 24 spoke wheel on a long distance (I asked [a separate question for this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72831/importance-of-spoke-count-for-touring)

I stumbled upon a [aluminium wheel with SONdynamo built into it](https://us.huntbikewheels.com/collections/dynamo-wheels/products/hunt-search-29-dynamo-disc-wheelset)

Does using the Hunt wheel (aluminum) on front and carbon wheel on rear makes sense?  Buying another Roval carbon 28 spoke wheel and building dynamo on it myself would cost me probably 2.5x the price.

Should I stick with carbon on front as well at least even if it's not the same model?

Comment: As long as the brakes are suitable (rim track or rotor size)   and the axle mount is the same, there's no problem using a different wheel.

Comment: In your position I would sell the carbon Roval wheels and buy a set of wheels that matches the type of riding you want to do. I.e, built in dynamo, higher spoke count and strong aluminium rims.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus The carbon rims are a better choice than aluminum. It’s far more likely for an aluminum rim to become bent or dented than carbon.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus that's a good strategy I didn't think of .. thanks, but top players ride 28 hole carbon wheels on TourDivide as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll be perfectly fine. A carbon rear wheel on a hardtail is actually a pretty good idea because of how much you’re smacking the back wheel around, thanks to the lack of suspension.

Comment: I'm not completely on board with the notion of carbon rear wheel being a good idea for hardtail. Yes, a hardtail will be ridden (or at least _should_) in a more front-heavy, rear-agile way than the “just slam all the weight over the rear wheel” style you can use when descending on a full-sus. OTOH suspension takes some of the load from the wheel at hard hits, making it less of a risk to crack a carbon rim. And the main advantage of a light wheel as opposed to just everything-lighter bike is reduced _unsprung_ mass, but that doesn't apply to a hardtail.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Any impact big enough to crack a carbon rim would have absolutely destroyed a comparable aluminum rim too. In normal use, a carbon rim will stay dead true “forever”, compared to an aluminum rim which you will slowly dent and bend. The lightness means you can use an overly strong rim: eg. enduro rim for XC, DH rim for enduro...

Answer (score -1):

> Now I want to install a dynamo on it. and found out there are not many dynamos for 24 spoke wheels.

There's a good reason for that. Quality wheels have standardized on 36 spokes for 622mm bead seat diameter for reasons of durability. Also some people use 559mm bead seat diameter wheels so 32 hole hubs are sometimes offered for use with these smaller rims. The 32 spokes on 559mm wheels have the same spoke density as 36 spokes for 622mm wheels.

> So using the hunt wheel (aluminum) on front and carbon wheel on rear makes sense?

The reason this does not make sense is not the front wheel. It's the rear wheel.

> Should I stick with carbon on front as well at least even if it's not the same model?

In my opinion, wheels that:

1. Have carbon rims
2. Have less than 36 spokes even though they are of 622mm bead seat diameter, or less than 32 spokes even though they are of 559mm bead seat diameter

...do not make sense.

Comment: there are plenty of durable & high quality  622 mm (700c) wheels with fewer than 36 spokes.

Comment: As someone who generally chooses 36 spoke wheels, and finds myself in the minority, I agree with @PaulH.  32 spokes is plenty for most uses and most riders.  Fewer can be suitable for some cases.  I'm heavy and take my tourer over rougher stuff than I perhaps should, quite far from support - so it's got 36.  My 29er hardtail rides rougher stuff but less laden and not so far from home - 32s.  All Al rims here but that's for cost reasons

Comment: What’s wrong with carbon rims? The whole point of having them is that they explode “suddenly and without warning” as you might say. Aluminum rims will not withstand the same kind of abuse you can safely do with carbon rims. Carbon rims won’t break until you grossly overload them, at which point an aluminum rim would have broken too.